# Problem with local variable inside an event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am developing a page which has a resizable and draggable div, and I have attached `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` event handlers to this div.

The problem is with the `mousemove` event handler. I have to get the current width, height, top and left of the div. For that I am using functions to return the specific values and I have to use these values in different conditions inside the main function.

If I try to assign local variables with these values and use these variables in the preceding code then the script becomes slow. Means there's a delay in the resizing and dragging.

But if I call the functions each time instead of using these variables in the condition then there's no delay.

Any idea what could be the cause of this problem?

***Code Sample***

```
// Code executes with a delay
function AdjustElement()
{
     var elemHeight = GetHeight ( elem );
     var elemWidth = GetWidth ( elem );
     var elemTop = GetTop ( elem );
     var elemLeft = GetLeft ( elem );

     if ( elemLeft >= 20 && elemRight <= 200 )
     {
        //code for moving element
     }
     if ( elemTop >= 20 && elemTop <= 200 )
     {
       // code for moving element
     }
     if ( elemHeight >= 60 && elemHeight <= 300 )
     {
       // code for resizing element
     }
     if ( elemWidth >= 60 && elemWidth <= 300 )
     {
       // code for resizing element
     } 
}

// Code executes without delay
function AdjustElement()
{
     if ( GetLeft(elem) >= 20 && GetRight(elem) <= 200 )
     {
        //code for moving element
     }
     if ( GetTop(elem) >= 20 && GetTop(elem) <= 200 )
     {
       // code for moving element
     }
     if ( GetHeight(elem) >= 60 && GetHeight(elem) <= 300 )
     {
       // code for resizing element
     }
     if ( GetWidth(elem) >= 60 && GetWidth(elem) <= 300 )
     {
       // code for resizing element
     }
}


// General functions
function GetWidth(elem)
{
   return elem.offsetWidth;
}

function GetHeight(elem)
{
   return elem.offsetHeight;
}

function GetTop(elem)
{
   return elem.offsetTop;
}

function GetLeft(elem)
{
   return elem.offsetLeft;
}
```

Comment: You need to express the problem clearer. What's the "main function" in the second paragraph? The event handler? What's the "condition" in the penultimate paragraph? It's best to add sample code, showing the slow and the fast variant.